# Sublime Text 3 - Snippets Library Team Workflow

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets, sublimetext3

I am Currently Migrating from Dreamweaver to Sublime Text 3, Sublime has a very handy snippets feature. Could this work in a team workflow?

Is it possible to synchronize everyone's snippets, Store all the snippets on a server and have every user synchronizes with that?

After a Few hours of searching around, Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Sublime text uses files to store anything: configuration / plugins / snippets / ext.

From the [docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html), the configuration folder:

> **Windows**: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3
>   **OS X**: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3
>   **Linux**: ~/.Sublime Text 3

So all you really need is to **synchronize that folder** with any sync tool you want.

Examples with dropbox:

- http://www.alexconrad.org/2013/07/sync-sublime-text-3-settings-with.html
- http://misfoc.us/post/18018400006/syncing-sublime-text-2-settings-via-dropbox
- http://juhap.iki.fi/misc/using-dropbox-to-sync-sublime-text-settings-across-windows-computers/

Answer (score 0):

Try **[Syncrow](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Syncrow/)**, You can **create snippets** on the go and **sync them in all your systems**.

Comment: Showcase an example pls

Comment: Check out the official repo https://github.com/Afzal7/syncrow, They have  a pretty simple example with gifs.